# How to parse request JSON data for DRF Serializer in custom format?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x, rest, django-rest-framework

I have DRF serializer that looks like this:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate(username=attrs['email'], password=attrs['password'])
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect email or password.')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User is disabled.')
        return user
```

When POST request is made to API it sends following JSON:

```
{
   "email": "user@example.com",
   "password": "somepassword"
}
```

Due to certain project conventions I want that data for deserialization to be included inside `request` object and sent to API in following format:

```
{
    "request": {
        "email": "user@example.com",
        "password": "somepassword"
    }
}
```

How I can make DRF's serializers (both `Serialize`r and `ModelSerializer`) automatically fetch data from `request` block without writing additional serializer with nested `LoginSerializer`?:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate(username=attrs['email'], password=attrs['password'])
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect email or password.')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User is disabled.')
        return user


class LoginRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    request = LoginSerializer()
```

Is there some type of `RequestRenderer` that I need to implement in my APIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use `.to_internal_value` method:

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior

Something like this should work:

```py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    password = serializers.CharField()

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data["request"]

    def validate(self, attrs):
        user = authenticate(username=attrs['email'], password=attrs['password'])
        if not user:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('Incorrect email or password.')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('User is disabled.')
        return user
```